# beautiful soup find tag within tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I read a bunch of articles and couldn't find anything really relevant. I promise :)
This is with BS4 and the lxml parser under python 2.7.3.

I had this:

```
self.chaptername = self.soup.find_all('center h3 b')
```

and in my html I have

```
<center><h3><b>Chapter 34</b></h3></center>
```

I would expect a result of ["Chapter 34"]  but I get an empty result set.

If I look for 'b' I get a result set of all the boldfaced text, (with the  attribute).

If I look for 'h3 b' I get anempty result set.

Am I supposed to be able to look for the `<center><h3><b>` nested structure, or am I using BS4 wrong?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: `find_all` returning a list ! so you've to iterate over it with `item.text` to extract the text! should be `[x.text for x in self.soup.find_all('center h3 b')]`

Answer (score 2):

You are making a call to BeautifulSoup's `.find_all()` function. This takes a [name argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-name-argument) which can be either a string, a regular expression, a list, a function, or the value True.

For a string, this should be a single tag's name, in your case you could use `center` to locate `<center>` tags. Using `name="center h3 b"` will not locate the text inside the `<b>` tag. A list is used if you want multiple types of tag returned in order, e.g. all `<h1>` and all `<h2>`.

Note, if you asked for the text of just the `<center>` tag, it would correctly display all text within it and so would give you `Chapter 34` without needing to locate the `<b>` tag.

If you only want to match `<b>` tags inside `<h3>` tags inside `<center>` tags then consider the following example to help make things a little clearer:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<center><h3><b>Chapter 34</b></h3></center>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for center in soup.find_all('center'):
    print("center soup:", center)           # all html soup
    print("center text:", center.text)      # all text        
    
    h3 = center.find('h3')
    
    if h3:
        b = h3.find('b')
        
        if b:
            print("b text v1:", b.text)

    # Alternative methods
    
    print("b text v2:", center.find('h3').find('b').text)
    print("b text v3:", center.h3.b.text)
```

This would display:

```
center soup: <center><h3><b>Chapter 34</b></h3></center>
center text: Chapter 34
b text v1: Chapter 34
b text v2: Chapter 34
b text v3: Chapter 34
```

Here `center` is used to locate a `<h3>` tag, if present this is used to locate a `<b>` tag, if present the text is displayed.

At each point, the `.find()` call can return `None` if the tag is not present so care should be taken to deal with this (which depends on the HTML being parsed).

BeautifulSoup offers a shorthand for doing a simple `.find()`, `center.h3.b` would be equivalent.

These last two examples could be wrapped in a `try / except` clause if there are cases which do not always have the correct structure.